# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined Nodejs/ejs/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Iam facing the error Cannot read property 'forEach of undefined' for two days long and I just coudn't solve the problem. Your help would be very helpful. The code below

**bruidstaart.js page where I want to show some data**

```
<div class="table-wrapper">

        <table class="table table-hovered">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Image</th>
                        <th scope="col">Bruidstaartnaam</th>
                        <th scope="col">Aantalpersonen</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <% bruidstaarten.forEach((bruidstaart, user) => { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="/assets/bruidstaartenmap/<%= bruidstaart.image %>" class="rounded-circle player-img" alt="" width="200" height="200"></td>
                        <td><%= bruidstaart.bruidstaartnaam %></td>
                        <td><%= bruidstaart.aantalpersonen %></td>
                    </tr>
                <% }) %>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

**index.js**

```
exports.bruidstaartenPage = function(req, res, next){
  var sql1  = "SELECT * FROM `bruidstaarten` ORDER BY id ASC"; // query database to get all the players
  db.query(sql1, function(err, result){
    res.render('bruidstaartenPage', {bruidstaarten:result});
  });
};
```

Comment: forEach is applicable only for arrays, so check what is the value of bruidstaarten ? if it is an array or not

Comment: Are you sure result is of type array and has valid data inside? Besides you should check if err contains anything for proper error handling. Maybe it will also tell you the problem.

Comment: Most probably `result` is undefined and so is `bruidstaarten` - check if the query was successful by evaluating `err` ...

Comment: For this and future problems, you might find https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ useful. As @eol says, `result` is likely undefined, maybe check `err` in index.js.

Comment: Hello Eol, Dcoder and Joe Pi, I have found the problem. the id was wrong in the database. It was my fault when creating the tabel. Thank you very much for your help. It works now

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by checking the query and the tabel in the database. id was wrong by creating the tabel